# UWP change CalendarDatePicker language in runtime

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, calendarview

I have an application that changes UI in runtime. Here is my code for changing language:

```
public void SwitchLanguage(SupportedLanguage language)
{
    // Check if passed argument is different from current language
    if (CurrentLanguage != language.Type)
    {
        // Set the new current language
        CurrentLanguage = language.Type;

        // Override tha application primary language ( it will automatically save the language preference )
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language.FourDigitCode;
        ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
        ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();

        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LocalizedResourceMap"));
        // Notify code about the changes
        this.LanguageChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

All localization works fine, except CalendarDatePicker - it's Flyout doesn't get localized ( in runtime, when i relaunch the app - all if fine ).

Here are the examples

Opened a page and selected CalendarDatePicker:

[image]

Switched the language to Russian:

[image]

I have tried to do this:

```
// Attach to LanguageChanged event - created in my own code
// And trigger this method inside CalendarDatePicker:
private void LanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Language = "ru-RU"; // Hardcoded value for test only
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

**I have also tried to invalidate() everything. Also tried to trigger TemplateChild CalendarView Update method - no use. Any suggestions how to achieve normal language change?**

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Elvis Xia, have been noticed that on language change in code, the CalendarView size gets screwed, because if i do this:

```
this.calendar.Language = "ru-RU"
this.calendar.Height = 500;
this.calendar.Width = 500;
```

I will get to see the dates ( screwed, but still ):

[image]

**Any ideas how to fix this?**

Comment: From the second picture, you mean the language has changed, but there is something wrong with the size of the calendar flyout?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT

I can't really tell that it is a size issue. It seems like dates part was not rendered - or maybe you are right, and size got broken. But why if i have changed the language only, not the day of the week - the dates should remain the same ( in theory )

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, you were right, something strange happens with flyout size

Answer (score 0):

So, as a dirty and nasty fix, i have set the CalendarView item height and width in XAML. Inside the CalendarDatePicker control template.

Width should be smaller than height at about 100px - the all works fine;

```
<CalendarView Height="400" Width="300" x:Name="CalendarView" ... />
```

But still this is not a solution