# How to change the year format in the Japanse Calendar Picker

Tags: c#, uwp, calendar

I have the Japanese Calendar Picker like this:

```
<CalendarDatePicker CalendarIdentifier="JapaneseCalendar"/>
```

The result is a calendar with the `yy` format, like (29,30), and I want to show it in `yyyy` format, like 2017 2018. How can I customize this?

Comment: Well, why did you change it to Japanese Calendar in the first place if you want it to be Gregorian style? Heisei 29 _is_ 2017.

Comment: cause i want everything in japanse format except year.

Comment: As far as I know, the only difference between the Japanese Calendar and the Gregorian Calendar is the year. Everything else should be the same.

Comment: Maybe you can just set the [Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.language#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Language) to Japanese?

Comment: not really, days in week is different too

Comment: That's why I said you might only need to change the `Language` property. Did that work?

Comment: where can i put that framework element ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677814/uwp-change-calendardatepicker-language-in-runtime). Seems like the same issue.