# UWP DatePicker control not localizing day month year string prompts

Tags: uwp-xaml

In my UWP app (built on VS2019), it is possible to change the language through the UI, where the language is then set via PrimaryLanguageOverride:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = sLang;
```

This subsequently results in the locale-specific resource file to be used, labels get updated to this locale, and everything works great. Except the DatePicker control.

As can be seen in these two screenshots, where the language was originally English upon startup and since been changed to French, the 'day | month | year' prompts remain in English even though clicking on the dropdown we see the names of the months automatically are correctly translated.

Please note that I HAVE tried explicitly setting the Language property for the DatePicker control - both as an attribute in XAML and programmatically in the ctor - but it has no effect.

Here are two related articles, however no viable solution concluded.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/bb492446-558e-4c15-829c-bbee316ad3c3/update-timepicker-to-current-primarylanguageoverride?forum=winappswithcsharp&prof=required
[UWP change CalendarDatePicker language in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677814/uwp-change-calendardatepicker-language-in-runtime)

Any ideas?

Thanks,
David

[image: DatePicker prompts in Eng from startup]
[image: DatePicker calendar months correct in Fra]

Answer (score 0):

> UWP DatePicker control not localizing day month year string prompts

`DatePicker` use some static resource to render style,  After modify the `PrimaryLanguage`, you need refresh your page manually or restart the app. Please add the following code into PrimaryLanguage setting method behind to reload current page, it will update the ui when you re-click picker.

```
Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
```

Comment: Thx @Nico for reply. The changing of the language (and call to PrimaryLanguageOverride) happens in the View-Model layer triggered from a binding on a page called Settings. The user has to navigate to another page (let's call it Details) to get to the DatePicker control, which means it is hitting the Details page's OnNavigatedTo() event.

So what do you recommend? Have you tried your proposed solution above and it actually works?

Comment: yes, I tried above it could work for DatePicker, if you are in viewmodel, please get frame with  `Window.Current.Content`  and refresh page or restart current app maually.

Comment: Any updates for this one ?

Comment: Thx for the followup @Nico. As mentioned above, the language is being changed on one page (eg Settings), and the DatePicker is on another page (eg Details). So Details is already being 'navigated to'. So forcing a navigation as you recommended isn't going to help as it already gets navigated to by the user, AFTER the PrimaryLanguageOverride is set.

The DatePicker.Language property is even being explicitly set in the Details page ctor, although it has no effect.

As mentioned in the original post above, restarting the app solves the problem but I want it to be updated dynamically.